# Android toolbar showing shadow when it shouldn't

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-support-design

I'm creating an app and I got my layout defined like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary_green">

    </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And toolbar.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarTheme">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_logo"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And AppTheme.ToolBar theme is defined as:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ToolbarTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_white</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

I've even tried setting the elevation in code, still the toolbar shadow is visible. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting shadow, because `AppBarLayout` is giving shadow for `Toolbar` too.

You should remove elevation also from it.

Comment: turns out I had to set the elevation of both in code, thanks!